# Received Azure data share not mapping to SQL db target - permissions error

Tags: azure, azure-data-share

We are testing the process for azure data share and have set up source shares from SQL db on our primary azure domain and shared them to accounts on our secondary azure domain.

We can accept the share invite and successfully map the source SQL data to blob storage but when we attempt to map the same share to a target SQL db we get the error:

> Mapping failed. Please check Troubleshoot Azure Data Share for help
> and try again.
>
> Data Share account's Managed identity is missing required permissions
> on database. For more details, please refer to
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-share/subscribe-to-data-share

We have followed all the troubelshooting tips and can confirm the Data Share external user has the 3 roles on the target db (db_datareader, db_datawriter, db_ddladmin).
We have also made the Data Share identity a SQL Db Contributor on the target SQL server.

Is there anything else we need to update or checks we can run to find out why the data share is not mapping to SQL target. We really need to prove this process before we offer it to our clients so any help that can be provided would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several **permissions are needed or conditions to access Database** from Azure DataShare resource's managed identity:

First Set   **`Azure Active Directory Admin`**   to yourself in SQL server. After becoming admin **Connect through** `Azure Active Directory authentication` to the Azure SQL Database using `SSMS` and then grant `db_datareader` permission to the  `Data Share Resource-Managed Identity` while granting this permission, **make sure you're connected to the database by Azure Active Directory authentication not SQL authentication.**

Comment: Thanks for your response - I should have updated this question with the response from MS.  The issue was a bug where the receive data share database was failing because it had '.' in the name.  A fix has now been developed and deployed by MS.